# How to use Context with flatMap() in Reactor?

Tags: java, project-reactor

I have a problem understanding **Context**. So documentations says that *Context* is:

> A key/value store that is propagated between components such as
>   operators via the context protocol. Contexts are ideal to transport
>   orthogonal information such as tracing or security tokens.

Great.

Now let's suppose we want to propagate something using *Context* to have it everywhere. To call another async code we simply use the **flatMap()** method.

**Problem**: *how to access Context inside called method?*

Sample (simple) code:

```java
public class TestFlatMap {
    public static void main(final String ...args) {
        final Flux<String> greetings = Flux.just("Hubert", "Sharon")
            .flatMap(TestFlatMap::nameToGreeting)
            .subscriberContext(context ->
                Context.of("greetingWord", "Hello")  // context initialized
            );
        greetings.subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

    private static Mono<String> nameToGreeting(final String name) {
        return Mono.just("Hello " + name + " !!!");  // ALERT: we don't have Context here
    }
}
```

The called method can be (and most likely will be) in another class.

Thanks for help in advance !

*Edit*: removed some code to make the question more concise and straight to the point.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Chain your `Publisher`s and may the `Context` be with you

In the case, you connected all your `Publisher`s (and this includes connections within the `flatMap`/`concatMap` and similar operators) you will have `Context` correctly propagated among the whole stream runtime.

To access `Context` in the `nameToGreeting` method, you may call `Mono.subscribeContext` and retrieve stored info event if it seems that methods are not related. 
The following shows the mentioned concept:

```
public class TestFlatMap {
    public static void main(final String ...args) {
        final Flux<String> greetings = Flux.just("Hubert", "Sharon")
                                           .flatMap(TestFlatMap::nameToGreeting)
                                           .subscriberContext(context ->
                                                   Context.of("greetingWord", "Hello")  // context initialized
                                           );
        greetings.subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

    private static Mono<String> nameToGreeting(final String name) {
        return Mono.subscriberContext()
                   .filter(c -> c.hasKey("greetingWord"))
                   .map(c -> c.get("greetingWord"))
                   .flatMap(greetingWord -> Mono.just(greetingWord + " " + name + " " + "!!!"));// ALERT: we have Context here !!!
    }
}
```

Also, you can do the same in the following way, using `zip` operator, to combine results later:

```
public class TestFlatMap {
    public static void main(final String ...args) {
        final Flux<String> greetings = Flux.just("Hubert", "Sharon")
                                           .flatMap(TestFlatMap::nameToGreeting)
                                           .subscriberContext(context ->
                                                   Context.of("greetingWord", "Hello")  // context initialized
                                           );
        greetings.subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

    private static Mono<String> nameToGreeting(final String name) {
        return Mono.zip(
            Mono.subscriberContext()
                .filter(c -> c.hasKey("greetingWord"))
                .map(c -> c.get("greetingWord")), // ALERT: we have Context here !!!
            Mono.just(name),
            (greetingWord, receivedName) -> greetingWord + " " + receivedName + " " + "!!!"
        );
    }
}
```

## So, why it works?

As we can see from the sample above, the `nameToGreeting` is called within the context of the main `Flux`. Under the hood -> [(Here Some FluxFlatMap internals)](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/FluxFlatMap.java#L389), each mapped `Publisher` is subscribed by `FlatMapInner`. If we look at the [`FlatMapInner`](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/FluxFlatMap.java#L877) and look for [the `currentContext` override](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/FluxFlatMap.java#L973) we will see, that `FlatMapInner` uses parent `Context`, which means if the parent has a Reactor `Context` - then this context will be propagated to each inner `Publisher`.

Therefore, returned by the `nameToGreeting` method `Mono` will have the same `Context` as its parent

Answer (score 11):

Reactor-Core v3.4 introduced [Mono.deferContextual](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#deferContextual-java.util.function.Function-) and [Flux.deferContextual](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#deferContextual-java.util.function.Function-), which supersede [Mono.deferWithContext](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#deferWithContext-java.util.function.Function-) and [Flux.deferWithContext](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#deferWithContext-java.util.function.Function-) introduced in v3.3.

Using these methods, [Oleh Dokukas zip example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54563449/5189777) can be simplified to

```
public class TestFlatMap {
    public static void main(final String ...args) {
        final Flux<String> greetings = Flux.just("Hubert", "Sharon")
                .flatMap(TestFlatMap::nameToGreeting)
                .subscriberContext(context ->
                        Context.of("greetingWord", "Hello"));  // context initialized
        greetings.subscribe(System.out::println);
    }

    private static Mono<String> nameToGreeting(final String name) {
        return Mono.deferContextual(c -> Mono.just(name)
                .filter(x -> c.hasKey("greetingWord"))
                .map(n -> c.get("greetingWord") + " " + n + " " + "!!!"));
    }
}
```

Comment: subscriberContext is deprecated. contextWrite(Function) can be used instead